# How to pass environment variables to a gem5 syscall emulation simulation?

Tags: gem5

For example, I have a test C program that prints all environment variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(void) {
    char **env = environ;
    while (*env) {
        printf("%s\n", *env);
        env++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/eb22fd3b6e7fff7e9ef946a88b208debf5b419d5/userland/posix/environ.c)

But when I run it in se.py syscall emulation, it does not print anything, so I'm guessing that gem5 has an empty environment set in syscall emulation by default instead of inheriting the host's.

Tested on gem5 872cb227fdc0b4d60acc7840889d567a6936b6e1.

Answer (score 0):

By doing a quick `se.py --help | grep -i env` we see:

```
  -e ENV, --env=ENV     Initialize workload environment from text file.
```

and so the following works as expected:

```
printf 'a=b\nc=d\n' > env.sh
se.py -e env.sh
```

and the test program prints:

```
a=b
c=d
```

Trying to use Bash's `<()` notation does not work however, gem5 really needs that to be placed in regular file, trying that fails with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/fd/63'
```